# How to copy IDataObject value to another IDataObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, copy, clipboard, idataobject

I want go get value from 'd' IDataObject to 'c' IDataObject in C# but my 'c' possess value from my Clipboard even when i won't click D key. How can I give independent value from one IDataObject to second?

First function:

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.D))
{
    d = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    c = d;      // <-- doesn't work
    string dd = d.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();      //content
    MessageBox.Show(dd);
}
```

Second function

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
{
    string dd = c.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();      //content
    MessageBox.Show(dd);
}
```

Comment: Clipboard may contain Metadata that you can't copy to the object as it is. Btw, the question is not clear. What do you want to achieve? Where copy data from and where to? Why `Clipboard`? What the condition? Inside one application or different applications? Do you need Clipboard listening, for example when some other application modify it and you want to read the changes e.g. after virtual pressing `Ctrl+C`? `IDataObject` is reference to the data, not the data itself.

Comment: I gonna click CTRL + C. I have value in my `d`. When i click D key this shows me it using messege box and copy to `c`. Now I again click ctrl + c marking another text. After that when I click S key it should show my old value from first ctrl + c but i have content from my actual clipboard.

Comment: I hope you know what i'm talking about bro.

Comment: I want to get content(text or image) from one variable to different one but it should take it even if it's text or image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a backup of `IDataObject`?

If it was possible in all cases it would look like this

**Backup**

```csharp
// expiremental list of formats to exclude. Doesn't cover all possible cases but most of it.
private static readonly string[] clipboardMetaFormats = { "application/x-moz-nativeimage", "FileContents", "EnhancedMetafile", "System.Drawing.Imaging.Metafile", "MetaFilePict", "Object Descriptor", "ObjectLink", "Link Source Descriptor", "Link Source", "Embed Source", "Hyperlink" };

private DataObject ReadClipboard()
{
    DataObject result = new DataObject();
    IDataObject dataObject = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
    string[] formats = dataObject.GetFormats()?.Except(clipboardMetaFormats).ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<string>();
    foreach (string format in formats)
    {
        try
        {
            object data = dataObject.GetData(format);
            if (data != null) result.SetData(format, data);
        }
        catch (ExternalException ex)
        { 
            Debug.WriteLine($"Error {ex.ErrorCode}: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

```csharp
DataObject backup = ReadClipboard();
```

Then you may use it as local data storage. For example in case you want to change `Clipboard`, use the changed value e.g. paste it into some application and the restore the previous data to `Clipboard`.

**Restore**

```csharp
private void UpdateClipboard(DataObject data)
{
    if (data == null) return;
    try
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
    }
    catch (ExternalException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Error {ex.ErrorCode}: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

```csharp
UpdateClipboard(backup);
```

---

But in your case that's a simple `string`. You may do it this way:

```csharp
string text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
```

```csharp
Clipboard.SetText(text, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
```

Comment: I need backup cuz I want to create multi clipboard function and when user will click ctrl+c program should save it to variable. When user click ctrl+c again old clipboard content should go to different variable and when i click one key my actual clipboard value should be replaced by old. I have this feature but only with texts. I need adjust it for texts and images(We have possibility to use printscreen button and it works like ctrl + c right)

Comment: @DawidSoChiiSokół try the solution then.

Comment: I will try it but tomorrow and give you feedback. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works! Thanks a lot! I have only one question to you. From where do you have information about that? I want learn more about your code. Do you have any useful link to read about it?

Comment: @DawidSoChiiSokół `IDataObject` is interface the object created by `Clipboard` and the object is being destroyed each time the clipboard changes. Also `Clipboard` may contain metadata that can't be backed up to the `object` instance, there should be more complicated solution to backup it. So, I ignore that things and that cause an `Exception` when you try to copy the entire `DataObject`. Thus I copy format by format ignoring everything I found that I can't copy. In a back way it works simply setting the entire `DataObject` to the `Clipboard`. I don't know where to read.

Comment: @DawidSoChiiSokół did I answered your question? Please mask the answer as accepted if I did.

Comment: I did it. What is it changing? I'm new on stackoverflow

Comment: @DawidSoChiiSokół Thank you! It means that answer is correct and suits your needs and other members may not try to answer. It gives 15 reputation to the author of the answer and 2 reputation to you.